# python tkinter: Make text widget automatically scroll with text (used with redirected stdout)

Tags: python, tkinter, text, scroll

I have STDOUT redirected to a text widget. 
Then I use threading to run a subprocess, capture stdout via poll() and print it (redirected to the text widget).

Now I want the widget to scroll automatically with the text widget, so that the user can see the latest output always..

(the only use of the text widget is to show the output of the running script, thus feel free to suggest alternatives)

```
class myGui:
  def __init__(self, master=none)
    self.text_Output = tk.Text(frame_Output)
    self.text_Output.config(borderwidth='1', height='10', insertborderwidth='2', relief='ridge')
    self.text_Output.config(width='50')
    # redirect stdout
    redir = RedirectText(self.text_Output)
    sys.stdout = redir

  def runCode:
   self.p = subprocess.Popen(["COMMAND HERE"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
    while self.p.poll() is None:
        msg = self.p.stdout.readline().strip()
        if msg:
            print(msg)


class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self, text_ctrl):
        """Constructor"""
        self.output = text_ctrl

    def write(self, string):
        self.output.insert(tk.END, string)
```

Comment: `Text` has method [see(...)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.see-method) which you could use after putting new text in `Text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Text` has method [see(...)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.see-method) which you can use after inserting new text.

If you use `see('end')` then it will scroll to the end.

---

Minimal working example - it scrolls to the end after every `insert()`

**EDIT:** I added buttons which use `see()` to scroll to the top (`see('1.0')`) or the end (`see('end')`).

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

button_top = tk.Button(root, text="Move to TOP", command=lambda:text.see('1.0'))
button_top.pack()

button_end = tk.Button(root, text="Move to END", command=lambda:text.see('end'))
button_end.pack()

# instert to Text and scroll it
for x in range(50):
    text.insert('end', str(x) + '\n')
    text.see('end')  # move to the end after adding new text

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** Minimal example which uses class `RedirectText`

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import datetime

# --- classes ---

class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self, text_widget):
        """Constructor"""
        self.output = text_widget

    def write(self, string):
        """Add text to the end and scroll to the end"""
        self.output.insert('end', string)
        self.output.see('end')

# --- functions ---

def add_time():
    """Add current time every 2 seconds"""
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    root.after(2000, add_time)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

button_top = tk.Button(root, text="Move to TOP", command=lambda:text.see('1.0'))
button_top.pack()

button_end = tk.Button(root, text="Move to END", command=lambda:text.see('end'))
button_end.pack()

# keep original `stdout` and assing `RedirectText` as `stdout`
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = RedirectText(text)

# add some datetime at the beginning 
print('--- TOP ---')
for _ in range(50):
    print(datetime.datetime.now())

# add new datetime every 2 seconds
add_time()

# write to console when `print()` and `sys.stdout` redirect to `Text`
old_stdout.write('Hello World!\n')      # needs `\n` 
print('Hello World!', file=old_stdout)  # doesn't need `\n`

root.mainloop()    

# assign back original `stdout`    
sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

---

**BTW:** If you need to print to console when `print()` is redirected to `Text`

```
old_stdout.write('Hello World!\n')      # needs `\n` 

print('Hello World!', file=old_stdout)  # doesn't need `\n`
```

**BTW:** You can also use `file=` to print without assigning `RedirectText` to `sys.stdout`

```
redirect = RedirectText(text)

print('Hello World!', file=redirect)
```

Comment: Nice, I learned something @furas, thanks

Comment: I added example which uses your class `RedirectText` - it can be also useful other users.

Comment: I added information how to print on console when `print()` is redirected to `Text`